# Stuff for XML Path Can't concatenate BIT type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a field that is a bit type that simulates a boolean, but I'm trying to concatenate the field into a string field using `STUFF FOR XML PATH` and it keeps giving me an error. Here's the Query:

```
select
    ui.IndivId,
    ui.correctedInFNV,
    ni.firstName,
    ni.prefName,
    ni.lastName,
    ni.suffix,
    ni.alreadyCorrect as nameCorrect,
    ni.updated as nameUpdated,
    ni.updatedDate,
    ni.correctPerson,
    ai.addr1,
    ai.addr2,
    ai.addr3,
    ai.city,
    ai.state,
    ai.zip,
    ai.country,
    ai.alreadycorrect as adcorrect,
    ai.updatedDate,
    ai.updated as adupdated,
    pi.priPhoneType,
    pi.priPhoneNumber,
    pi.updated as phoneupdated,
    pi.updateddate,
    ei.priEmailType,
    ei.priEmailAddress,
    ei.alreadycorrect as emailcorrect,
    ei.updated as emailupdated,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+pos.positionTitle from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS POS_TITLE,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+pos.positionId from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId for XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as POS_ID,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+pos.positionCode from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId for XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as POS_CODE,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+pos.areaServed from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId for XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as POS_AREA,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+pos.districtServed from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId for XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as POS_DIST,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+pos.reason from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId for XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as POS_REASON,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+pos.currentlyHeld from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS POS_HELD
from 
    updatedInfo as ui
    join nameInfo as ni on ui.IndivId=ni.nameInfoId
    join addressInfo as ai on ui.IndivId=ai.addressInfoId
    join phoneInfo as pi on ui.IndivId=pi.phoneInfoId
    join emailInfo as ei on ui.IndivId=ei.emailInfoId
    JOIN positionInfo AS pos ON ui.IndivId=pos.IndivId
```

When this is run, I get the error

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 36 The data types varchar and bit are
>   incompatible in the add operator.

It's screaming about the final `STUFF` statement for `pos.currentlyHeld`.
So I try to convert or cast the field to a char type like this:

`STUFF((SELECT ','+CAST(pos.currentlyHeld AS VARCHAR(1)) FROM positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS POS_HELD`

Then it screams at me because of a comma somewhere? Not sure.

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value ',' to data type int.

Where is the syntax issue? or is this more data type issues?

Comment: Without trying to disentangle everything -- if you have SQL Server 2012 or later, consider using `CONCAT(',', column)`. It will always convert to strings without getting tangled up by the default conversions.

Comment: instead of Stuff?

Comment: No, instead of `',' + column` (`',' + 1` is invalid because SQL Server preferably converts strings to integers, instead of the other way around, like sane systems would).

Comment: Assuming currentlyHeld is a BIT...      STUFF(SELECT concat(',',pos.currentlyHeld) From ...

Comment: Oh it is a BIT type

Comment: Just realized I can't use `CONCAT()`. This is a 2008 server.....

Comment: No. You are concatenating a comma `','` with a value you have casted as a varchar `CAST(pos.currentlyHeld AS VARCHAR(1))`. using a PLUS sign `+` which would usually be kosher, but SQL Server is deranged and it believes you are trying to ADD the two things together so it's converting your comma to an integer and throwing up on itself. Toss all this CASTing and `+` concatentating away and use the `Concat()` function instead.

Comment: If you're restricted to SQL Server 2008, consider using `',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), column)` for every column. I wouldn't waste brain cycles thinking about whether the column already has a suitable type.

Comment: @JeroenMostert just tried, but it's still giving the comma issue. This is the only BIT type for this query, so I think it would be overkill to convert every other field as they're already nvarchars

Comment: Okay, I did the same conversion for all fields being merged, and it works!

Comment: Consider posting your final working query as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering this question was for a SQL Server 2008 implementation, the `CONCAT()` function is not available.

As suggested, the query should have all fields converted over to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` within each of the `STUFF` statements.

The final query is as follows:

```
select distinct
    ui.IndivId,
    ui.correctedInFNV,
    ni.firstName,
    ni.prefName,
    ni.lastName,
    ni.suffix,
    ni.alreadyCorrect as nameCorrect,
    ni.updated as nameUpdated,
    ni.updatedDate,
    ni.correctPerson,
    ai.addr1,
    ai.addr2,
    ai.addr3,
    ai.city,
    ai.state,
    ai.zip,
    ai.country,
    ai.alreadycorrect as adcorrect,
    ai.updatedDate,
    ai.updated as adupdated,
    pi.priPhoneType,
    pi.priPhoneNumber,
    pi.updated as phoneupdated,
    pi.updateddate,
    ei.priEmailType,
    ei.priEmailAddress,
    ei.alreadycorrect as emailcorrect,
    ei.updated as emailupdated,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),pos.positionTitle) from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS POS_TITLE,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),pos.positionId) from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId for XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as POS_ID,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),pos.positionCode) from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId for XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as POS_CODE,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),pos.areaServed) from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId for XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as POS_AREA,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),pos.districtServed) from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId for XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as POS_DIST,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),pos.reason) from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId for XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as POS_REASON,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), pos.currentlyHeld) from positionInfo as pos where pos.IndivId=ui.IndivId FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS POS_HELD
from 
    updatedInfo as ui
    join nameInfo as ni on ui.IndivId=ni.nameInfoId
    join addressInfo as ai on ui.IndivId=ai.addressInfoId
    join phoneInfo as pi on ui.IndivId=pi.phoneInfoId
    join emailInfo as ei on ui.IndivId=ei.emailInfoId
    JOIN positionInfo AS pos ON ui.IndivId=pos.IndivId
```

The `DISTINCT` Keyword was used to keep from having a row for each entry in the `PositionInfo` table, which was the purpose of stuffing the values into POS fields.

Many thanks to everyone who contributed to this question.